# How to alphabetically sort the columns in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, periscope

So my boss asked us to sort the columns alphabetically so the clients will have an easier time locating the column they want. The pictures below show what I mean by that. 
Currently, the columns are shown in an order like this: [original layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVIK3.jpg)

However, what I am trying to achieve is like this: [sorted columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yx3B3.jpg)

As you can see the columns are sorted alphabetically but I did that manually. I am trying to figure out a way to let the code do it. Even though it sounds like a fairly simple goal, it has taken me tons of time and all my approaches turn out to be nothing but dead ends. *I am running my codes on Periscopedata.com and I think they use Redshift by Amazon.*

The engineers at Periscopedata helped me a lot, and their approach is this:

```
CREATE TABLE  #ordercolumns as SELECT attname::varchar as column_name 
from pg_attribute WHERE attrelid='devices'::regclass::oid and 
attnum>=1;


SELECT 'SELECT ' || LISTAGG(column_name, ',')  within group (order by 
column_name)  || ' FROM devices' FROM #ordercolumns;
DROP TABLE #ordercolumns;
```

I was wondering if I could do something like:

```
select (select * from ordercolumns) from devices
```

Sorry if I didn't explain my questions well enough.

I wanna thank you guys ahead of time as this community has helped me tremendously since I was in college.

---

update: I wanna thank you for all your help. We try to avoid any type of manual sorting because we have hundreds of clients and each client has different columns they want to see. So sorting columns manually is going to take too long with very little accuracy. thank you

Comment: Do it once manually and store the results as a view.  Voila!  Done.

Comment: Hi Gordon. thank you for your reply. Based on what you suggested, does it mean I'll have to do this for every table I got?

Comment: For each table, you should create a view with the columns in the order that your boss wants them.

Comment: couldn't find anything related to `amazon-web-services` tag in this question.

Comment: @kintuparantu the code was running in redshift but stackoverflow wouldn't let me use that tag unless i have more reputation or something.

Answer (score 0):

You could rearrange the order of the columns with something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `devices` 
    CHANGE COLUMN content content VARCHAR(255) FIRST,
    CHANGE COLUMN date date DATE AFTER `content`,
    CHANGE COLUMN id id INT(11) AFTER `date`,
    ....
;
```

Just be sure to check the data types of each column and as always make a backup of the table before making any changes.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. We try to avoid any type of manual sorting because we have hundreds of clients and each client has different columns they want to see. So sorting columns manually is going to take too long with very little accuracy. thank you